# Embedded web parts in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel-web-access-webpart, embedded

So I made a link to a document from one subsite to another subsite in sharepoint. 
I have used the embed web part and have inserted the link to the document instead of the iframe code. The document is an excel file but only half of the document is shown and there are no side bars to scroll across. how do I adjust the size of the embedded web part or the excel file? Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use the file viewer web part instead?

Comment: I would have preferred to have it embedded, but using the file viewer was my back up. Just wanted to see if there were any possibilities out there.

Answer (score 1):

This is design. The excel file in the embed web part can only be displayed a part. You could not adjust the size of the embedded web part or the excel file. The only way is click the Full Screen at the Lower right corner of the web part. This would open a new tab for the file.

[image]